# strange redirect with url rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (.*) index.php?_url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It works perfectly in most cases. But if the requested url exists as a real folder, it goes crazy.

For example when i request `/random` it is rewritten to `index.php?_url=random` with status code 200, but for `/static` (which is an existing directory on the web server) it gives a 301 redirect to `/static/?_url=static`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use this below code for .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: But then how can i get the original request uri from php?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude existing files and directories from being rewritten, do so with a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?_url=$1 [QSA,L]
```